# Cannot evaluate module FacebookLib : Configuration with name 'debug' not found - Facebook Integration

Tags: gradle, ionic-framework, facebook-javascript-sdk, build.gradle

I've followed the steps below and got this error message when trying to build my Ionic App.

I think it is caused by a gradle structure error. I have a settings.gradle and a build.gradle on my app root, a build.gradle on CordovaLib and a build.gradle on phonegap-facebook-plugin/FacebookLib.

1> ionic platform add android

2> cordova -d plugin add /path_to_cloned/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="123456789"--variable APP_NAME="myApplication"

3> gradlew.bat assembleDebug

4> error msg:

> C:\myApp\platforms\android>gradlew.bat assembleDebug
>
> Loading> Loading > settings
> Loading > settings > Compiling C:\myApp\platforms\android\settings.gradle into local build cache
> Loading > settings > Compiling C:\myApp\platforms\android\settings.gradle into local build cache > Compiling settings file 'C:\myApp
> Loading > settings > Compiling C:\myApp\platforms\android\settings.gradle into local build cache
> Loading > settings
> Loading > settings > Compiling C:\myApp\platforms\android\settings.gradle into local build cache
> Loading > settings > Compiling C:\myApp\platforms\android\settings.gradle into local build cache > Compiling settings file 'C:\myApp
> Loading > settings > Compiling C:\myApp\platforms\android\settings.gradle into local build cache
> Loading > settings> Loading
>
> Configuring> Configuring > 0/4 projects
> Configuring > 0/4 projects > root project
> Configuring > 0/4 projects > root project > Resolving dependencies ':classpath'
> Configuring > 0/4 projects > root project
> Configuring > 0/4 projects
>
> Configuring > 1/4 projectsObserved package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\luigg_000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\temp\ToolPackage.old01' (Expected 'C:\Users\luigg_000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools')
> Configuring > 1/4 projectsObserved package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\luigg_000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\temp\ToolPackage.old01' (Expected 'C:\Users\luigg_000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools')
>
> Configuring > 1/4 projects
> Configuring > 1/4 projects > :CordovaLib
> Configuring > 1/4 projects > :CordovaLib > Resolving dependencies ':CordovaLib:classpath'
> Configuring > 1/4 projects > :CordovaLib> Configuring > 1/4 projects
>
> Configuring > 2/4 projectsIncremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
> Configuring > 2/4 projects> Configuring > 2/4 projects > Resolving dependencies ':CordovaLib:_debugUnitTestApk'
> Configuring > 2/4 projects> Configuring > 2/4 projects > Resolving dependencies ':CordovaLib:_releaseUnitTestApk'
>
> Configuring > 2/4 projects
> Configuring > 2/4 projects > :phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib
> Configuring > 2/4 projects > :phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib > Compiling C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.38-0\apache2\htdocs\PROJETO_GIT\convem-front-end\platforms\android\phonegap-facebook-plugin\FacebookLib\build.gradle
>
> Configuring > 2/4 projects > :phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib
> Configuring > 2/4 projects > :phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib > Resolving dependencies ':phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib:classpath'
> Configuring > 2/4 projects > :phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib> Configuring > 2/4 projects
>
> Configuring > 3/4 projects > Resolving dependencies ':phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib:_debugPublish'
> Configuring > 3/4 projects> Configuring > 3/4 projects > Resolving dependencies ':phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib:_releaseCompile'
> Configuring > 3/4 projects> Configuring > 3/4 projects > Resolving dependencies ':phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib:_debugAndroidTestApk'
> Configuring > 3/4 projects> Configuring > 3/4 projectsFAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>   Cannot evaluate module FacebookLib : Configuration with name 'debug' not found.

settings.gradle (root)

```
// GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT
include ":"
include ":CordovaLib"
include ":phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib"
project(":phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib").projectDir = new File("phonegap-facebook-plugin/FacebookLib")
```

buil.gradle (FacebookLib)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  jcenter()
}

project.group = 'com.facebook.android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:[20,21)'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.2'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

def isSnapshot = version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')
def ossrhUsername = hasProperty('NEXUS_USERNAME') ? NEXUS_USERNAME : ""
def ossrhPassword = hasProperty('NEXUS_PASSWORD') ? NEXUS_PASSWORD : ""

task setVersion {
    // The version will be derived from source
    project.version = null
    def sdkVersionFile = file('src/com/facebook/FacebookSdkVersion.java')
    sdkVersionFile.eachLine{
        def matcher = (it =~ /(?:.*BUILD = \")(.*)(?:\".*)/)
        if (matcher.matches()) {
          project.version = matcher[0][1]
          return
        }
    }
    if (project.version.is('unspecified')) {
      throw new GradleScriptException('Version could not be found.', null)
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

        repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
            authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
        }

        snapshotRepository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
            authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
        }

        pom.project {
            name 'Facebook-Android-SDK'
            artifactId = 'facebook-android-sdk'
            packaging 'aar'
            description 'Facebook Android SDK'
            url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'

            scm {
                connection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
                developerConnection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
                url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'
            }

            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/LICENSE.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }

            developers {
                developer {
                    id 'facebook'
                    name 'Facebook'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

uploadArchives.dependsOn(setVersion)

signing {
    required { !isSnapshot && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
    sign configurations.archives
}

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}

afterEvaluate {
    androidJavadocs.classpath += project.android.libraryVariants.toList().first().javaCompile.classpath
}
```

build.gradle on root and on CordovaLib where working before facebook integration.

Thanks!